# How do i apply a filter to a px.Histogram

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly

im currently writing code which is plotting a histogram containing all traces at the top and a second one that plots each histogram in its own subplot below that. i want to apply a filter to these histograms (they are energy spectrums) using a sigmoid function. so far everything ive tried didnt work or shifted the x scale out of proportion. i basically want to modify each count value of the resulting bins with a function thats depending on the bin center.

'''

```
if spectrum_main_option.value == "Specific thickness":
        
        dftemp=data_frames[spectrum_sub_option.value]
        
        fig = go.Figure()
        
        
        # Iterate through each column in the DataFrame and create histograms
        for col in dftemp.columns:
            fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=dftemp[col],nbinsx=bins, name=col))

        # Update the layout
        fig=add_lines(targetMat,fig)
        fig.update_xaxes(title_text="photon energy in keV")
        fig.update_layout(title='Histogram of all acceleration voltages')
        fig.show()
        
       
        fig = make_subplots(rows=len(row_titles)+1, cols=1, row_titles=row_titles)    
        for j, col in enumerate(dftemp.columns):
            
            trace = px.histogram(dftemp, x=col, nbins=bins)
            fig.add_trace(trace.data[0], row=j+1, col=1)
            
            
            fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, showgrid=True, row=j+1, col=1)
            fig.update_xaxes(title_text='photon energy in keV', row=j+1, col=1)
            
          
        
        
        
        

            

        fig=add_lines(targetMat,fig)
        fig.update_layout(title=f"showing plots of {spectrum_sub_option.value}",height=6000, width=1000)
        fig.show()
```

'''

ive had these attempts so far which all didnt work

'''

```
def sigmoid(x, k=1, x0=0):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-k * (x - x0)))
for j, (df_name, df) in enumerate(data_frames.items(), start=1):
    dftemp = df.iloc[:, tempIndex]
    filtered_data = sigmoid(dftemp, k=1, x0=0)
    trace = go.Histogram(x=filtered_data
```

'''

and

'''

hist_data, bin_edges = np.histogram(dftemp, bins=bins)

filtered_data = [sigmoid(bin_center) * count for bin_center, count in zip((bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:]) / 2, hist_data)]

'''

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take care to format all code as code, and add a representative data sample.